# VSTS Release error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Server'

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a PowerShell script that contains this at the top:

```
Param(
    # [snip]
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Server
)
```

In my VSTS Release definition, I added an Azure Powershell task calling the script, and passed the argument as:

```
-Server '$(ServerName)' [snip]
```

However, when I trigger a new Release, at the step for this script, I get this error:

```
##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Server'.
```

I verified in the log output that the server name is passed properly. I even copy/pasted the command logged, and after fixing paths, it ran locally with no problems.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It _sounds_ like there was an earlier definition of your script/function loaded.

Comment: @Matt Can you elaborate on that? If that was the case, shouldn't that mean that [changing the parameter name](//stackoverflow.com/a/39730146/2747593) would not affect anything?

Comment: Yeah I know. Its a series of timing errors I am suggesting that I cannot reproduce as I don't have the environment. It would be like you made v1 of the script and it did not have that name then you "published" it. Next you update the script to make it better but neglected to "publish" it. Then testing would fail as you would assume a version is there that is not present. Then, finally, you test again with v3 of the script and "publish" with testing going smoothly. That would have the appearance of changing the name being what fixed it. Suggesting that correlation does not equal causation.

Comment: @Matt Ah okay. I don't think that's what happened in this case, since there is no manual publish in the process, but the script is automatically published as a build artifact. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of the argument fixed the issue. My script now contains:

```
Param(
    # [snip]
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ServerName
)
```

And I pass the arguments as:

```
-ServerName '$(ServerName)' [snip]
```

As for the why, I can only speculate. I checked the [source code](//github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShell/AzurePowerShell.ps1) but couldn't find anything obvious. My only guess is that the Azure PowerShell task overwrote `$Server` for some reason (though I'm not sure why the log output would show the correct argument in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Your `$Server` variable is already declared. I give you some trick when you want to test code or something like this. First remove variable and clear screen like this example:

```
cls
Remove-Variable server
function ssssss 
{
    param
    (
        [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$server
    )
    Write-Host $server
}
ssssss -server "Enter servername here"
```

It's working fine.

Comment: I don't think this will work for my case. When I added the `Remove-Variable` call to my script, running in VSTS gave the error `Cannot find a variable with the name 'Server'.` As I mentioned in [my answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/39730146/2747593), I think VSTS must be doing something strange that mangles some variables as a side effect.

Comment: `$server` would only have context locally to the function. I don't think this is a scope issue.

Comment: this is example you can wite remove-variable in last line of your function

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was the way I was passing the arguments to the task,
When I passed all in one line it actually worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30854884)